# Embed row of data from dataframe into single vector or array values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, feature-engineering

Is there any way I can embed or any process to capture each of the row data turn into vector, or array number which is in shape (1,)?

[image]

My intention is to embed each of the rows information become something to representative input feature, so that I can convert 1x3 shape from DataFrame into 1. For example,

```
row [1,6,5]  become =====> [2.178] //sample array number only, not necessary 2.178
row [1,10,3] become =====> [3.415] //sample array number only
row [1,12,5] become =====> [0.888] //sample array number only
```

Is that any libary available? or does my request make sense?
Thank you in advance for your view.

To generate data sample,

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd 
  
# initialize list of lists 
sample_dat = [[1, 10, 5], [1, 10, 3], [1, 12, 5]] 
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_dat, columns = ['userId', 'movieId', 'rating'])
```

Comment: What is formula for `row [1,6,5]  become =====> [2.178]` ? How is count `2.178` ?

Comment: Hi, there is no certain formula, the 2.178 is just a sample output I simply create, it just want to shows a single dimension arrray.

Comment: So need `sample_df['mean'] = sample_df.mean(axis=1)
print (sample_df[['mean']].to_numpy())` ?

Comment: I see, means you are suggesting use mean value to represent each row data. I have try it just now but I afraid this representative method is not suitable for my case.

Comment: It was reason why I ask what is formula. Because you need any function here for procesing per rows like `.sum(axis=1)`.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Unfortunately, there is no formula for this. It is something like squeeze the entire row data turn into a single value as representative. I trying using flatten.

Comment: ok, but what is rule of `single value as representative` ? What is conversation?

Comment: Thank you @jezrael, I think I should think further about it, as I currently in a clueless situation.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you are trying to hash an array right? So each different row has a different number (that does not really mean anything but you are confident that no other array has this number)? You could just do  `[hash(sample) for sample in sample_dat]`